# Regex for filename at end of href attribute (replace filepath with filename)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the filepath with just the filename using regex, and struggling.

I take a list of text like this:

```
xlink:href="file://C:\x\y &amp; DRAWINGS\z - CONTROLLED\a \testsvg-A01.svg"
```

and i just want to output

```
xlink:href="testsvg-A01.svg"
```

I can get there with separate regex (javascript) with several bits of regex as such:

```
let inQuotes = hrefs[0].match(/"(.*?)"/gm);
inQuotes = inQuotes[0].match(/([^\\]+$)/gm);
inQuotes = inQuotes[0].replace(/"/g, "");
```

this will return just the filename, but i was wondering if there was a way to take this and replace the original text to the desired style.

EDIT:

i can get it for a single occurrance with this line of code:

```
let testHrefs = outText.match(/xlink:href="(.*?)"/gm)[0].match(/"(.*?)"/gm)[0].match(/([^\\]+$)/gm)[0].replace(/^/, 'xlink:href="');
```

but it looks awful and doesn't completely do what i want. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to remove the text you don't want to keep (i.e. everything between the `href="` and the filename:

```js
let href = 'xlink:href="file://C:\\x\\y &amp; DRAWINGS\\z - CONTROLLED\\a \\testsvg-A01.svg"';
console.log(href);
console.log(href.replace(/href=".*?([^\\\/]+)$/, 'href="$1'));
```

Note I've used `[\\\/]` to allow for Unix and Windows style filenames, if you only want Windows style filenames that can simply be `[\\]`.

Comment: Thanks! this is great. Is there a way i can do this for multiple lines though? ie. if there is a list of hrefs in text, can i change them all in this format?

Comment: I just did a string.split and replaced every specific line, this worked wonders. Thanks a bunch Nick!

Answer (score 1):

First, keep in mind that backslashes in strings need to be escaped, as the backslash *itself* is an escape character. You'll likely want to escape these as `\\`.

After doing this, you can make use of a positive look-behind on the `\` with the regex `(?<=\\)[^\\]*`:

```js
var xlink = "file://C:\\x\\y & DRAWINGS\\z - CONTROLLED\\a \\testsvg-A01.svg";
var regex = /(?<=\\)[^\\]*/gm;
console.log(xlink.match(regex));
```

This splits the string into each of the folders (which may be useful within itself), though if you exclusively want the filename, you can use `xlink.match(regex)[4]` (assuming the length is consistent), or `xlink.match(regex)[xlink.match(regex).length - 1]` if it isn't.

```js
var xlink = "file://C:\\x\\y & DRAWINGS\\z - CONTROLLED\\a \\testsvg-A01.svg";
var regex = /(?<=\\)[^\\]*/gm;
console.log(xlink.match(regex)[xlink.match(regex).length - 1]);
```